# Limit number of characters imported from SQL in R

Tags: sql, r

I am using the sqlquery function in R to connect the DB with R. I am using the following lines

```
for (i in 1:length(Counter)){
if (Counter[i] %in% str_sub(dir(),1,29) == FALSE){

DT <- data.table(sqlQuery(con, paste0("select a.* from edp_data.sme_loan a
                            where a.edcode IN (", print(paste0("\'",EDCode,"\'"), quote=FALSE),
                            ") and a.poolcutoffdate in (",print(paste0("\'",str_sub(PoolCutoffDate,1,4),"-",str_sub(PoolCutoffDate,5,6),"-",
                            str_sub(PoolCutoffDate,7,8),"\'"), quote=FALSE),")")))}}
```

Thus I am importing subsets of the DB by EDCode and PoolCutoffDate. This works perfectly, however there is one variable in edp_data.sme in one particular EDCode which produces an undesired result.

If I take the unique of this "as.3" variable for a particular EDCode I get:

```
unique(DT$as3)
[1] 30003000000000019876240886000 30003000000000028672000424000
```

In reality there shoud be more unique IDs in this DB. The problem is that the string of as3 is much longer than the one which is imported.

```
nchar(unique(DT$as3))
[1] 29 29
```

How can I import more characters from this string? I do not want to specify each variable in select a.* ideally, but only make sure that it imports the full string of as3.

Any help is appreciated!